# How do I detect minimization in an inactive Win32 app?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

My app should always minimize to the system tray, instead of to the task bar.

To do so, I handle `WM_SYSCOMMAND`/`SC_MINIMIZE`:

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    switch (wParam)
    {
        case SC_MINIMIZE:
            minimizeToTray();
            return FALSE;
        ...
```

This, however, does not cover events where the window gets minimized without a `WM_SYSCOMMAND`.

For example: I can minimize the window by using `Win+D` (show desktop).

To cover this case, I handle `WM_ACTIVATE`/`WA_INACTIVE`:

```
case WM_ACTIVATE:
{
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == WA_INACTIVE && HIWORD(wParam) != 0)
    {
        minimizeToTray();
    }
    ...
```

Which seems to *only* work if the window is active before showing the desktop.

---

**Problems:**

When the window is already inactive, no `WM_ACTIVATE` comes in to detect minimization. Which message tells me that the inactive window gets minimized?

*EDIT: It seems that `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is the right place to check if the window is minimized, when it is not active.*

Furthermore, when I activate some other app that is maximized, fully covering my own app, I also want to minimize to tray, but don't know if there's a message to handle in that case. The high word of the `wParam` for `WM_ACTIVATE` is `0` in that case (like it would also be if the window was just deactivated but still visible).

Comment: Huh, seems that Win+D not sending the minimize signal is kind of an oversight on MS part.

Comment: Well yes, that's MS for ya... I'll have to make due with the current state of affairs though.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Win + D (Show Desktop) and Win + M (Minimize All) keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://winaero.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-win-d-show-desktop-and-win-m-minimize-all-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows/): "*When you press Win + M, the OS sends a special message, WM_MINIMIZE, to all windows, and they should get minimized to the taskbar...  when you press Win + D, the operating system will hide windows which cannot be minimized*"

Answer (score -1):

Call IsIconic(hWnd) to get the current state.

Comment: `IsIconic(hwnd)` yields exactly the same as the high word as `WM_ACTIVATE`.
When I maximize another app over my app, `IsIconic(<my hwnd>)` will yield `false`.

Furthermore: _where_ should I call `IsIconic`? I clearly state that there is no `WM_ACTIVATE` when the window is already inactive.

Comment: Relevant to this comment thread: WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED seems to be the place. Edited the question to include this.

Comment: WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED is the event to get notified about a change. IsIconic() is to request the current state.